# Is there an RDBMS that supports indexing by a part of a key. See inside

Tags: mysql, key, rdbms, partial

Say, I have a table with an index on `(field1,field2,field3)` . I execute a query with `WHERE field2 = A AND field3 = B` . MySQL won't use the mentioned key in this case. So, question is: is there an RDBMS that WOULD use this index? I mean - use it effectively?

PS Please, do not tell me to add an extra key to a table. I just want to know an RDBMS that supports the mentioned feature, if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to add the extra index? This works fine in any RDBMS without any adverse effects I can think of.

Comment: Yes, other DBMS can do this. Oracle describes it as a skip-scan. But what's the point of the question? Adding an index is a lot less hassle than changing than migrating across DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

<s>So I'm not sure why you think that MySQL does not support this behaviour -- does `EXPLAIN` tell you othewise?.</s>  (sorry, I mis-read the question)

You are correct: from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multiple-key indexes:

> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statement shown here:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
>
> If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3), the above query does involve indexed columns, since (col2, col3) are not leftmost prefixes of (col1, col2, col3).

If you're against adding another index (as sugested by others), my only suggestion for MySQL is perhaps to make 2 single-column indexes and try to benefit from the index merge optimization that's available in more recent version of MySQL.  Whether that is more efficient or not depends on the cardinality of these individual indexes, and what the rest of the query load looks like.

Comment: The OP isn't using col1; that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible answer to the apparent problem would seem to be to just create another index.

```
create index on table_name (field2, field3);
```

I'd be surprised if MySQL's optimizer decided not to use that index for the query you describe.